# T-SQL: select words with specific hebrew dots using dot code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hebrew, collate

The code of one of the hebrew characters which is a dot(=vowel) is 1463 or 0x05b7

I try to select only words that contain this character, but I get the whole list of words.

I try:

```
DECLARE @d NCHAR
set @d = NCHAR(1463)
select * from words where word like '%' + @d + '%'
```

I tried also

```
select * from words where word LIKE '%'+NCHAR(0x05B7)+'%'
```

I tried to finish the statement with

```
collate hebrew_cs_as
```

or

```
collate hebrew_cs_ai
```

and it's not working

PS when I try the same with a letter code like 1488 it is working fine

eg.

```
select * from words where word LIKE '%'+NCHAR(1488)+'%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the correct results if you `COLLATE` the source nvarchar as `Latin1_General_BIN`

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(txt NVARCHAR(4000));
INSERT INTO @t(txt)VALUES
    (NCHAR(1463)),(N'abcdef'),(N'aiiy'+NCHAR(1463)+N'skj'),(N'sdljsd'),(N'sdjp'+NCHAR(1463)),(N'sdzf');
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE txt COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE N'%'+NCHAR(1463)+N'%';
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: great! it works also when I use collate hebrew_bin, and without the N before '%'

Comment: @EliCohen Ah yes, any `*_BIN` collation will do. The `N`'s aren't strictly necessary if there aren't any unicode characters in it, but I always do that for nvarchars.